# Math resources for game programming

Tags: math, physics

Well I'm interested in learning the mathematics and physics applied to game development (I don't care about the language right now), I know there are many books related but I can't find them in my country so I have to buy them in amazon, I would like someone to recommend me some book to start and some good free resource if there is.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried this. It is extremely hard. If you dont have an education in higher level maths (specifically complex, trig and matrix algebra) you will struggle like I did. I gave up.

Comment: Agree with @leppie, there are plenty of engines to take care of this for you for every language / framework. Basic physics are easy enough to achieve with a little bit of work but without having an extremely high level understanding of advanced concepts in both math and physics you have no chance of succeeding. More importantly, there's about a 0% chance that you could even come close to improving on what's already out there.

Comment: Here's an example of basic collision detection and the complexity involved in just that: http://www.sevenson.com.au/actionscript/sat/

Comment: In general, questions asking for recommendations are a poor fit for stackexchange sites. You might try search [gamedev.se] to see if they have any good resources, eg [this search](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=book). Please don't just post this q there without first doing some investigation as to how well it would be received, though.